# Starting Letty on port 80 with Apache stopped

Tags: java, apache

I have a vserver (Debian Squeeze, 32Bit) with Apache preinstalled.
I installed Letty and stopped the Apache server.

Now when I start Letty on standard port 8080, my webbrowser will show me the Letty
startpage when I enter http://[myserverip]:8080 into it.
When I configure the Letty port to 80 and start it, my browser shows me the Apache start page ("It works!") when I enter http://[myserverip] into it.

Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear cache | use another browser to be sure it's not client related